# onsubmit() does not work

Tags: javascript, forms

Here is something that I find disturbing.  I created a small form, and I'm using AJAX to validate for me.  I have a javascript function authenticate() that works *sometimes*.

`<form method="post" action="" id="login_form" onsubmit="authenticate()";>`

`// various inputs`

`<input type="button" onclick="authenticate()" value="Log In">`

`</form>`

`authenticate()` works just fine when I click the button.  However, if I press enter the form is *submitted*, and it fails.  It also fails if I call onSubmit().  In my debugging, I alert the outgoing texts-- they are identical.  However, the Prototype Ajax function calls it the onSuccess, but there is just no response from the server.  (The server outputs either "Success" or "Failure").

Why the different behaviors for onClick() vs onSubmit()?  The exact same function is called, but the results are different.

Any help would be appreciated.

--Dave

Comment: What is the expected side effect of `authenticate()`?  Do you intend for the form to post back to the current page URL?

Comment: You're using Prototype for Ajax calls, why not for event handling? Get rid of that old inline stuff and use a modern DOM event handler on the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button's `onClick` does not submit the form.  It is merely a button that calls `authenticate()` on the client side.

Your `onSubmit` event will be called when the form submits, but you may not be seeing the result of the client side `authenticate()` because the form will post immediately after.  It's not clear what functionality is intended.

But, if `authenticate()` does what I guess, then you need to change the attribute to `onSubmit='return authenticate()'` and let the function return true/false.  When false, the form submission will be aborted.

Comment: "...the form will post immediately after..."

I think I understand what is happening now.  I actually don't want a submission, but I like the form behavior, and Prototype provides a nice serialize function for forms.

Thanks!

Comment: We can validate form first by doing button's "onclick" function, and can submit the form once validation passes. So we don't need use submit() functions.